# Windows Server 2022 RDP connection fails with error 0x3 + extended error 0x7

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2022

In an existing environment, where RD Session Host was previously in operation, an additional RD Virtualization Host is now to be set up.
This is installed on a Windows 2022 Datacenter Server and a collection is set up.

When I try to connect to this collection via the web portal I get an error message.

Errorcode: 0x3

Extended Errorcode: 0x7

I have already checked everything, and I am slowly at a loss as to what the problem is that it does not want to connect.

Does anyone here have an idea what I can look for?

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. serverfault.com ist nur der letzte punkt der reise

Comment: Provide the message received by the native RDC client, and the events in the Remote Desktop Windows event logs.

Answer (score 0):

It is failed RD Connection Broker service. It should start automatically but in my case due to update installation failed to start on server reboot. Starting `tssdis.exe` service manually fixed the problem.